# Docker host OS: Ubuntu or CentOS

Tags: docker

I am starting a project based on Docker Community. First of all I need an OS on which install Docker software and host the containers: are there any reasons to prefer one distro on other ones? It has to be a solid infrastructure, and it will host very 'regular' software (PostgreSQL DB and Apache web server) so I would prefer stability over cutting edge features.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question should be flagged as primarily opinion-based, but I'll try to answer you as concisely as I can.

In order to select which Linux distribution you want to use for a Docker host you should ask yourself a few questions and read [the official Docker docs section about installing Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).

- Do you need the Docker Cloud Edition or the Docker Enterprise Edition?.
- Do you need the stable or the edge version for Docker CE?
- What storage driver are you willing to use? [Different storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#docker-ce) have different behaviours and not all are supported by Linux distros.

Comment: I edited my question with the details you asked me.

Answer (score -1):

I would use whatever you are more comfortable with.

Though I believe Ubuntu has more up to date releases in the repositories?

Comment: That is opinion based. And this is, why the Q got that close-vote.